# Photoshop CS6 and NetBeans very sluggish and laggy on new rMBP 2014

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, adobe-photoshop

So I have this problem with Photoshop CS6 and NetBeans being very sluggish and laggy on my new rMBP 2014 15" 16GB RAM. It's running perfectly fine on my iMac 2009 21" 4GB RAM school computer, except for the occasional lag of RAM.

Activity Monitor shows that there's plenty of RAM and CPU power at all times, and still it's so sluggish and laggy.

Specs:
Processor  2,2 GHz Intel Core i7,
Memory  16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3,
Graphics  Intel Iris Pro 1024 MB,
Software  OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)

Does anyone have any idea on what is causing this and how I could possibly fix it?

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to drag their preferences files out onto the desktop and restart the apps - they will build new ones, though you'll have to enter your settings again.

You might check if these are taking App Naps - look in Activity Monitor.